# Compiling an eclipse GWT project from the command line, without eclipse: compile error

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, command-line, compilation

We got a GWT project in Eclipse, that otherwise works.
Now I want to have a script that runs on the server, which pulls the latest version from source control and compiles it on the server and deploys it. 
This will save us a lot of manual work and allow us to deploy new version when on a connection with limited bandwidth (since we won't have to upload the application to the server).

After pulling the latest version of the source code, the script tries to compile the code using the following command:

```
java -cp "/path/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.5.0.v201211121240-rel-r42/gwt-2.5.0/*:/path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/src:/path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/war/WEB-INF/lib/*" com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler nl.company.projects.X

Compiling module nl.company.projects.X
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'nl.company.projects.X.client.XMain'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
         [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

All source code is in `/path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/src` and all used .jars (except for the GWT stuff) are in `/path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/war/WEB-INF/lib/`. Obviously something goes wrong.

**Questions:** The file `/path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/src/nl/company/projects/X/client/XMain.java` does exist and should imho be in the classpath?!
Anyone Any idea what might go wrong here?
Is it maybe possible to see in some log exactly the commands that eclipse executes for compilation? I looked at the build.xml that eclipse can export, but it seems that does not contain a target to compile for production.

something else: apperantly GWT expects the `X.gwt.xml` to be at `/path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/src/nl/company/project/X.gwt.xml`, whereas eclipse put it in `/path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/src/nl/company/project/X/X.gwt.xml` (i.e. nested one directory deeper), I fixed this by creating a symbolic link.

**Further Edit:**
Since one answer focused on how I invoked the compilation tools, I have rewritten that in Ant, see below. 
The problem remains of course.

```
<!-- Compile the source using javac. -->
<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="src/" destdir="bin/">
        <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>


<!-- Use the GWT-compiler. -->
<target name="gwt-compile" depends="compile">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="project.classpath"/>
            <pathelement location="src/"/>
            <pathelement location="bin/"/>
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx512M"/>
        <arg value="${module.name}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Anything wrong with the above Ant-script?
`module.name = nl.company.projects.X` and the path with `refid="project.classpath"` contains all used libraries aswell as the GWT libraries (gwt-user.jar, gwt-dev.jar and validation-api-1.0.0.GA(-source).jar).

The XMain class inherits nothing (other than from Object) and only implements EntryPoint (which is included in the gwt-user.jar). So I do not think the problem is related to the second hint that the compiler gives.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT requires you to `javac` your classes, it needs both the `*.java` and the `*.class` files.

This has not always been the case, and should change back in the future (see https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7602 for instance), but for now that's the state of affair: you need to `javac` before you can `com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler`.

```
javac -cp "/path/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.5.0.v201211121240-rel-r42/gwt-2.5.0/*:/path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/war/WEB-INF/lib/*" -sourcepath /path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/src /path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/src/nl/company/projects/X.java -d /path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/bin

java -cp "/path/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.5.0.v201211121240-rel-r42/gwt-2.5.0/*:/path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/src:/path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/bin:/path/company/projects/pull-compile-deploy/X/X/war/WEB-INF/lib/*" com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler nl.company.projects.X
```

(please double-check the above commands before use)

**EDIT:** (in response to your "question" re. the `X.gwt.xml`): GWT *expects* the X.gwt.xml at `nl/company/projects/X.gwt.xml` because that's what you told it to use: `module.name = nl.company.projects.x`. If the file is at `nl/company/projects/X/X.gt.xml` then use `nl.company.projects.X.X` as the module name. Using a symbolic link here is likely to be the problem: the source path for the module (search for `<source` at https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModuleXml) will then be `nl/company/projects/client` and thus won't include `nl/company/projects/X/client` where your `XMain` class lives; it's this *unavailable* to the GWT compiler.

---

That said, I totally agree with SSR: use a decent build tool: Ant, Maven, Gradle, Make, whatever, it'll make your life so much easier. A build tool that manages dependencies (Ant+Ivy, Maven, Gradle) is even better IMO.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware I had to compile using the regular compiler first. However this does not seem to solve my problem.

Comment: The symbolic link was the problem. Really would like to have some version control on my brain, cause I have no clue why I ever thought that that was needed/a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Why would you put yourself through such **non-standard** build exercise like this.

If it is non-academic project then USE maven. If you find maven difficult then use ant.

Examples for both type are provided by GWT team - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsamples.

Note - maven has plugins to do most of the stuff you are trying in **standardized** way.

Comment: This is somewhat insulting and doesn't answer the OPs original question in anyway. Suggesting that maven might make this easier is fine, as long as it's paired with an actual answer to the question.

Comment: i have shared the example links from GWT sample for ant and maven based projects !!! T.Broyer works in GWT team and does mention at the end of the selected answer that ant/maven/gradle are the choices!!!

Comment: I find the command line option wonderful. I need to trigger the building / compiling along with additional requirements easy to manage. I will not ditch into the maven hell just to get a custom build processing going on. So I found it very good to have this option to easily available.